# Couldn`t design the timer in VHDL properly

Tags: vhdl, fpga, quartus

I have only started with the FPGA and I have a problem. I need the counter to activate only after the logical state of input srab equals to 1. However the statement seems to ignor it. After uploading the program to the FPGA ALTERA Cyclone IV leds (c1, c2, c3) do not light up. The problem that button (srab) is not starting program: **the button is not pushed leds are not working; the button is pushed leds still are not working; the button is released leds still are not working.**
How do I solve the problem.
P.S. Here is the code

```
 library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity MRZ is 
port (srab: in bit; clk: in STD_LOGIC; c1: out STD_LOGIC; c2: out STD_LOGIC; c3: out STD_LOGIC);
end MRZ;

architecture behaviour of MRZ is
begin
process(clk)
variable cnt : integer range 0 to 27000000;
begin
if(srab = '1')
then
    if(clk'event and clk = '1' and srab ='1')
    then 
    cnt := cnt + 1;
        if(cnt<=10000000)
        then  
        c1 <= '1';
        c2 <= '0';
        c3 <= '0';
        elsif(cnt>=11000000)
        then 
        c3 <= '1';
        c2 <= '0';
        c1 <= '0';
        else
        c2 <= '1';
        c1 <= '0';
        c3 <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
else 
cnt:= 0;
end if;
end process;
end behaviour;
```

P.S.S. Sorry I am new to FPGA...

Comment: _However the statement seems to ignor it_ is not enough to understand your problem. How did you test your design? What did you see that looked wrong? Note that your two `if` statements are redundant. In any programming language you would not write `if(condition1) { if(condition1 and condition2) { ...`

Comment: Thank you again. I editted the problem I hope that it is now more clear.

Answer (score 1):

As you apparently want to synthesize this for an FPGA target you must first understand that for synthesis there are 2 types of process.

1. Synchronous:

   ```vhdl
   process(clk)
   begin
     if rising_edge(clk) then
       <everything else>
     end if;
   end process;
   ```

   They model hardware structures which outputs are register outputs. All statements are between `if rising_edge(clk) then` and the corresponding `end if`. Nothing outside, never (unless you have asynchronous set or reset but let's ignore this).
2. Combinatorial:

   ```vhdl
   process(a, b, c...)
   begin
     <whatever>
   end process;
   ```

   They model glue logic without memory elements. As soon as any input changes electrical signals start propagating from inputs to outputs and, after the propagation delay, the outputs stabilize to the new value. For this second type there are 3 very important rules to remember:

   - all signals that are read in the process body must appear in the sensitivity list,
   - all variables must be assigned before they are read,
   - all signals that are assigned somewhere in the process body must be assigned during all possible executions of the process (not in just one of the branches of an `if` or `case` statement).

   Plus a fourth rule (but it's not local to a single process): no combinatorial loops.

Your process is not synchronous and it is not combinatorial. This cannot work. If your counter shall be reset when `srab` is low try:

```vhdl
process(clk)
  variable cnt : integer range 0 to 27000000;
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    if srab = '0' then
      cnt := 0;
    else
      cnt := cnt + 1;
      c1 <= '0';
      c2 <= '0';
      c3 <= '0';
      if cnt <= 10000000 then
        c1 <= '1';
      elsif cnt >= 11000000 then 
        c3 <= '1';
      else
        c2 <= '1';
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

See? All statements are between `if rising_edge(clk) then` and the corresponding `end if`. This is a true synchronous process. It is equivalent to the following combination of combinatorial processes (for all computations) and synchronous processes (for the registers and only that):

```vhdl
signal cnt, cnt_next: integer range 0 to 27000000;
signal c1_next, c2_next, c3_next: std_ulogic;
...
process(srab, cnt)
begin
  if srab = '0' then
    cnt_next <= 0;
  else
    cnt_next <= cnt + 1;
  end if;
end process;

process(srab, cnt_next, c1, c2, c3)
begin
  if srab = '0' then
    c1_next <= c1;
    c2_next <= c2;
    c3_next <= c3;
  else
    c1_next <= '0';
    c2_next <= '0';
    c3_next <= '0';
    if cnt_next <= 10000000 then
        c1_next <= '1';
      elsif cnt_next >= 11000000 then 
        c3_next <= '1';
      else
        c2_next <= '1';
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    cnt <= cnt_next;
    c1  <= c1_next;
    c2  <= c2_next;
    c3  <= c3_next;
  end if;
end process;
```

Note that there are two potential issues with your design:

- `cnt` can overflow and you don't do anything against this,
- when `cnt` is reset `c1`, `c2` and `c3` are not updated.

Note: do not use `ieee.std_logic_unsigned`, it is not standard and deprecated since a very long time. Use either `ieee.numeric_std` or `ieee.numeric_std_unsigned`.

Note: do not use `std_logic` without a very good reason. By default use `std_ulogic`.

Comment: Thank you very much, did not have enough time to learn it properly! I will correct it.